# change img src when hovering over other buttons jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to adjust the side image of a site, each button should change the image to a different src, I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#introID").hover(function(){
        $("#frame").attr("src", "newImage.png");
   });
});
```

and a few other variations but for some reason the jquery is not catching ? Or perhaps it is something with my syntax? From my inderstanding i just have to

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CAPP</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#introID").hover(function(){
        $("#frame").attr("src", "assets/images/much-more-than-gasoline.png");
    });
});


</script>
<body>

<div id="logodiv">
<img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo"/>
</div>

<div id="h1s">
<img src = "Origionalimage.png" id="frame"/>

    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <a class = "h1" href="" id="introID">Intro</a>

    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <a class = "h1" href="">ON THE <span class="light">SURFACE</span></a>

    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <a class = "h1" href="">From <span class="light">ore to oil</span></a>

    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <a class = "h1" href="">Environmental <span class="light">care</span></a>

    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <a class = "h1" href="">Much more than <span class="light">gasoline</span></a>

    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <a class = "h1" href="">One more <span class="light">thing</span></a>

</div>




</body>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not embed your own script inside a `script` tag if the `src` attribute is set.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#introID").hover(function(){
            $("#frame").attr("src", "assets/images/much-more-than-gasoline.png");
        });
    });
</script>
```

That should do the trick. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) you will find more information.